# Bool array to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any build in function in python to convert a bool array (which represents bits in a byte) like so:

```
p = [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

into a byte array like this:

```
bp = byteArray([233])
```

I am aware oh numpy but I was looking for something within python itself

Comment: @vaultah the boolArray corresponds to `11101001` in binary which is `233` in dec

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
sum(v << i for i, v in enumerate(p[::-1]))
```

Comment: `reversed` should be better then slicing `[::-1]` since you don't need a copy in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Just use algebra:

```
sum(2**i for i, v in enumerate(reversed(p)) if v)
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert integer strings in different bases, simply use the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function with an
appropriate base.

```
>>> int(''.join('1' if i else '0' for i in p), 2)
233
```

Using generators (`[1 if i else 0 for i in p]`) have a more performance than `map` (`map(int, p)`)here !

Comment: If you choose to use list comprehension or generator expression with conditional expression, why not use string literals: `int(''.join('1' if i else '0' for i in p), 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), you can convert binary representation to `int` object (by specifying base 2):

```
>>> p = [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
>>> int(''.join(map(str, map(int, p))), 2)
233
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> p = [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
>>> int("".join(map(lambda x: x and '1' or '0',p)),2)
233
```

int with base 2 give integer from binary

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I wanted to do the same thing.

Mine was an X/Y problem, however: I was implementing a function and thought that I wanted to convert the input array of bits into an integer.

What I *really* wanted to do was to use an [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag) from the `enum` built-in instead of my custom implementation.

Here's the standard example from the documentation:

```
>>> from enum import IntFlag
>>> class Perm(IntFlag):
...     R = 4
...     W = 2
...     X = 1
...
>>> Perm.R | Perm.W
<Perm.R|W: 6>
>>> Perm.R + Perm.W
6
>>> RW = Perm.R | Perm.W
>>> Perm.R in RW
True
```

It also works the other way:

```
>>> Perm(7)
<Perm.R|W|X: 7>
```

---

My use case was for a bitmask:

```
class BitMask(IntFlag):
    flag1 = 2**0
    flag2 = 2**1
    flag3 = 2**2
    flag4 = 2**3
    flag5 = 2**4
    # etcetera
```

---

With an IntFlag I can get the integer value while still retaining the useful information of what each bit represents.